Quotient group structure of general linear group
I want to find all quotient group structure in $GL(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which is all n*n invertible matrix on real number. The quotient group structure in $GL(\mathbb{R}^n)$ means to find normal subgroup $N$ in $GL(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and describe the structure of $GL(\mathbb{R}^n)/N$
This suffices to find all normal subgroup in $GL(\mathbb{R}^n)$. And I have found two of them: $SL(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $Z(GL(\mathbb{R}^n))$ which is the center of $GL(\mathbb{R}^n)$
So we have $GL(\mathbb{R}^n)/SL(\mathbb{R}^n)\cong \mathbb{R}^{*}$.
(For each $A\in GL(\mathbb{R}^n), A=\det^{1/n}(A)\det^{-1/n}(A)A$, since $\det^{-1/n}(A)A\in SL(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $\det^{1/n}(A)$ constructs $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}=\mathbb{R}^*$)
.
And $GL(\mathbb{R}^n)/Z(GL(\mathbb{R}^n))\cong PGL(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ which is the projective linear group.
Is(Are) there exist other normal subgroup(s)?
Thanks in advance!
Edit:
I have found another: $GL^+(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Certainly, any   subgroup of the center is a normal subgroup. For instance the subgroup $\{ \pm I_n \}$ is normal.
In fact it is known that $PSL_n(R)$ is simple, so any proper normal subgroup of $GL^+(n,R)$ is contained in the group $\Delta _n$ of matrices of the form $\lambda. I_n$, as $PSL_n(R)= GL(n,R)^+/ \Delta _n$ .
